# How does a ws2812b chip work?

Tags: led, ws2812b

- I know what a ws2812b chip does, but how does it work internally?
- How can it control the led?
- Is there a datasheet that goes into detail?

Comment: Ik likely uses a microcontroller, a dedicated logic circuit is also possible but I doubt that that is used. To control the LEDs (there are 3, Red, Green and Blue) **PWM** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation to switch /off faster than human eyes can see by changing the on/off ratio the brightness can be controlled) is used. No, the datasheet doesn't tell you the **design** as that is **company confidential**. Datasheets focus on **using** the device. With an Arduino and an RGB LED you can make a very similar device.

Comment: ... except at the scale those are produced,  it's very likely to be an ASIC (application specific integrated circuit)... for form factor, price,  yield, etc.  reasons.

Comment: The ws2812b led datasheet does tell you the design. Its the same as the individual ic ws2812b with an external led connection typical wiring diagram

Comment: In addition to what @Bimpelrekkie said, every WS2812B has a small logic circuit that reads the 1/0 pulses coming into its Din pin (at a speed of 800kHz). After the first 24 pulses, the first WS2812B in a string has received the G, R and B values (in that order) to light its own LEDs. Every pulse coming in after that, it sends through its Dout pin, that in its turn is connected to Din of the next WS2812B, that will also decode its GRB values and so on. There’s a little more to it, but that’s the general idea.

Comment: @bimpel many datasheets have block diagrams available as well telling you exactly how it works internally.

Answer (score 6):

If you know what it does, you're darn near to knowing how it works: there's not that much magic in there. I've put all the terms you should look up in *italics*:

- it's got its own *oscillator* on-chip to generate some *clock* for internal use
- functionally, it's a 24-bit *shift register*. Around that is a bit of *finite state machine* (fsm) to know whether we're shifting in data or are in some "reset" and "transmission finished" *state*s (read the datasheet – it's not great, but it describes the timing and *state transitions*). To know whether something on DIN lasts long or short, it will probably compare the duration to the number of internal oscillations.
- after detecting that the data currently in the shift register should be *latched*, that fsm loads the three 8-bit values in the shift register into three *PWM* units, which are clocked from the internal clock at ca 400 kHz to produce different amounts of *duty cycles* for each of the three LED current sinks.

And that's it. It's a three-channel PWM'ed current sink chip integrating three LEDs, controlled from a one-wire bus.

Comment: Yes, that is simple enough to be created as combinational logic, without any core.

Comment: it also bypasses the remaining data on to the next part in the chain. consuming the first one it sees after reset then passing through the rest.